# PHP get contents of table

Tags: php, html

So I have a webpage that has a table that is filled using the results of a MySQL query using some PHP code. I am trying to capture the data stored in the table once it has been filled by the PHP code. The table allows the user to edit the information therefore i cannot use the original query results instead i must get the current state of the table.

I have been trying simple html dom to get the contents of the file then finding the table elements and putting them into an array. This works perfectly fine when executing this code in a separate PHP file but i cannot fathom how to get it working from within the same file.

This is the code i have working in a different PHP file:

```
//Include the simple dom libary
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Start output buffer capture.
ob_start(); 
//Read the file
include("Manage-Projects.php");
//The file thats been read in 
$output = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean(); // Clear the buffer.

$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load file thats been read in 
$html->load($output);

//Find the table
$single = $html->find('#projectsTable', 0);
$theData = array();

//Go through each row of the table and store the results in an array
foreach($single->find('tr') as $row) {
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $rowData = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
    }

    // push the row's data array to the 'big' array
    $theData[] = $rowData;
}
```

The problem comes when i want to execute this code with the Manage-Projects.php file itself. I have been trying to use `file_get_contents` instead of the buffer method to account for it being ran within the same file its reading then it doesn't allow the PHP to run therefore the table is empty.

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: You should learn JS and learn how PHP works properly to achieve what you want.

Comment: PHP is exectuted once. And this is before the client starts rendering the page. so when the page is rendered you can't access the changed content without the help of html or js.